# Select a column based on a variable

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am looking for a way to access a variable column using a specified value. I have a data structure that matches 1:1 to my SQL database:

```
class Message
{
    int MessageId;
    string MessageType;
    /* more fields */

    double? Metric1;
    double? Metric2;
    /* cont'd */
    double? Metric10;

    /* database computed values */
    int Year;   
    int Month;
    int Day;    
}
```

How would I, using LINQ to SQL, do aggregation (Sum, Average) on a specific "Metric *n*" field based on the value of a variable?

Example:

```
/* DataContext Messages; */
int metric = 2;

var results = Messages
    .GroupBy(m => new { m.Year, m.Month })
    .Select(g => new {
        Year = g.Key.Year,
        Metric = g.Sum(m => m.MetricN) /* Here, MetricN should reflect the 
                                          value of (int metric) ("Metric" + metric) */
    });
```

Requirements:

- (int metric) is dynamically set (not known in advance, i.e. I am fetching the value from a Metrics definition table, based on a name).
- MetricN fields will always be of the same type.
- Fluent syntax preferred.

I know that putting the metrics in a separate table (with columns (MessageID, Metric and Value) would simplify requests, but this is the data structure I have to work with.

Is my only solution to hand-write my SQL requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using Dynamic LINQ.  It allows you to use string expressions instead of Lambda expressions.

It would end up looking something like this:

```
var results = Messages
    .GroupBy(m => new { m.Year, m.Month })
    .Select("new (Key.Year as Year, Sum(Metric1) as Metric)");
```

You'd just have to generate the select expression string outside of the query however you want to do that.

There is a version if Dynamic LINQ on Nuget here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library/

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error: `ParseException: No property or field 'Metric1' exists in type 'IGrouping\`2'`. Any idea?

Comment: Does Metric1 exist in your Message entity model?

Comment: I got it under control: I was not using the correct Dynamic Linq library (i.e. not yours)

It works!

Comment: A generic solution to this kind of question is to use my product AdaptiveLINQ (http://www.adaptivelinq.com).
The AdaptiveLINQ `.QueryByCube` function applies to all objects of type `IQueryable`.

The concept of cube consists of defining dimension (the expressions by which you want to group data) and measures (aggregation expressions). 
**These dimensions and measures are defined in C#**. Thus enjoying all the comforts of a strongly typed language contrary to the solution based on *Dynamic LINQ*.